# Attaching a flat, round, large diameter cover plate to a hollow casting

Tags: mechanical-engineering

A 200mm diameter, 10mm thick bearing plate needs to be attached to a hole in a 10-15mm thick walled, hollow cast iron (or more likely cast steel) casting.

The plate needs to sit flush to the surface of the casting body, so a rebate will be machined into the underside of the plate periphery, with an accepting rebate in the casting.

Usual solution: a myriad of small diameter machine screws going through holes in the plate and into threaded holes in the casting.

Problems:

1. The fixings, as well as the plate, need to be flush; dictating countersunk screws, thus small diameter (M4 or M5) which in turn requires even more myriad screws that normally might be the case. That in turn leads to several potential problems:
   a) through holes create leaks; but blind holes of this dimension are a pain to thread en masse.
   b) many small holes in the middle of the mating/sealing surfaces lead to weak gaskets or a mass application of RTV.
   c) sheared screws and/or stripped threads.
2. Large diameter, thin plates fixed by many screws tend to get warped unless tighening sequences and torques are strictly adhered to during assembly and maintenance.
3. Removal of plates this way after prolonged use in dirty environments -- ie. rusted -- is a nightmare almost guarenteed to need the application of substantial localised heating which inevitably results in warping.

Possible alternative:

Machine 6 or 7 turns of a 1mm pitch thread around the periphery of both components and a substantial chamfer applied to both inner and outer edges of both to aid alignment and starting.

Add a couple (or more) (stoppered) blind holes in the body of the plate to allow the use of a pin wrench for tightening/loosening of the plate and one or 2 small set screws cutting the visible join between the parts to secure against accidental unscrewing.

Seems a viable solution mechanically, but I've never attempted to machine -- either manually on a lathe or using cnc -- 200mm diameter internal and external threads.

Are there any forseeable problems I'm not foreseeing?

Is there a better solution?

Thanks for expert advice.

@Solar Mike The centre of the plate contains a boss containing a 30mm ID angular ball bearing which supports one end of a rotating mechanism internally. Insetting the plate into the casting with a close tolerance fit will easily support the envisaged radial loads.

The main purpose of the M4/M5 contersunk screws are to create and maintain a seal between them. The rotating mechanism exerts minimal axial load.

My main concern is that it is far too easy to overtighten and strip such small screws; and the inevitable rust. Even if stainless screws are used, the plate and casting can not be.

Comment: Would be neat to build as one part.  DMLS tends to be pretty comparable to cast, opening up some potentially interesting additive options too...  Friction weld is another specialty  solution but could work, but no removal of plates just like the one part solution.

Comment: What loads will this plate support? will M4 or M5 bolts be sufficient?

Comment: @Solar Mike If I used enough of them :)

Comment: Obviously this question is too ... simple, esoteric, whatever; for this place. Any suggestions for a better place to ask it?